# Random Variables and Probability Density Function

Tags: random-variables

I'm having a little trouble with a homework problem. I will write out what I've figured out and would appreciate some help with what I'm unable to understand.

**You flip a weighted coin four times. Assume that Pr [Heads]=0.7 and Pr [Tails]=0.3. The random variable X is defined to be 4 times the number of heads minus 1 times the number of tails.**

So landing four heads would result in an X value of 16 and the probability is .7^4. And landing four tails would result in an X value of -4 and the probability is .3^4. I have the X values for the other three scenarios but I'm having trouble calculating their probabilities.  I know that the probability values for all events must add up to 1.

So for example, if I flip 1 heads and 3 tails, X=1. I was trying .7*.3^3 to find the probability, but I realize I'm making a mistake in this calculation. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ be the number of heads. Then the number of tails is $4-Y$, and $X=4Y-(4-Y)=5Y-4$.

The values taken on by $X$, that is, by $5Y-4$, are $-4$, $1$, $6$, $11$, and $16$. We find $\Pr(X=a)$ for $a=-4$, $1$, $6$, $11$, and $16$.

$\Pr(X=-4)$: This is the probability of $0$ heads in $4$ tosses. This probability is $(0.3)^4$.

$\Pr(X=1)$: This is the probability of $1$ head in $4$ tosses. The *binomial distribution* tells us that the probability of $1$ head and therefore $3$ tails is $\binom{4}{1}(0.7)^1(0.3)^3$.

$\Pr(X=6)$: This is the probability of $2$ heads and therefore $2$ tails. It is $\binom{4}{2}(0.7)^2(0.3)^2$.

Similarly, $\Pr(X=11)=\binom{4}{3}(0.3)^3(0.7)^1$ and $\Pr(X=16)=(0.7)^4$.

**Remark:** Suppose we repeat an experiment independently $n$ times, and the probability of success on any trial is $p$, and the probability of failure is $1-p$. Then the number $W$ of successes in the $n$ trials has binomial distribution, and $\Pr(W=w)=\binom{n}{w}p^w(1-p)^{n-w}$.

Comment: Oh so it's pretty much a Bernoulli trial?

Comment: Your random variable $X$ is $5Y-4$ where $Y$ has binomial distribution $n=4$, $p=0.7$. So the distribution of $X$ is closely related to the binomial distribution, except that the values are $-4,1, 6,11, 16$ instead of $0,1,2,3,4$.  I would call what we have fond the probability distribution function of $X$.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. The question was closely related to stuff you already know.